# Is getting another user's ID token possible?

Tags: google-oauth, scribe

I'm working on a web app where all users sign in using their Google account, using [Google's OAuth2 API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). I'm using [ScribeJava](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava) to take care of the OAuth details.

I'm currently using the "sub" field of the user's ID token as their primary key in my database. When a new user logs in for the first time, their "sub" is stored for future logins.

I'm looking for a way for an administrator to add a user before they first log in - however, since I don't have the new user's "sub", I can't just add them to the database. Is there a way to use Google's API to look up another user's ID token (or at least the "sub" field) using their email address? Is there a better primary key that makes this easier?

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying using the Sub id is probably a really good idea.  However there is no way for you to get a users sub id from their email address.   That information just isn't available until a user logs in as its part of the authentication Open Id connect claims.

Sorry but what you want to do isnt possible.